# How to get token or code embedding using Codex API?

Tags: python, transformer-model, openai-api, language-model

For a given code snippet, how to get embedding using the Codex API?

```
import os
import openai
import config


openai.api_key = config.OPENAI_API_KEY

def runSomeCode():
    response = openai.Completion.create(
      engine="code-davinci-001",
      prompt="\"\"\"\n1. Get a reputable free news api\n2. Make a request to the api for the latest news stories\n\"\"\"",
      temperature=0,
      max_tokens=1500,
      top_p=1,
      frequency_penalty=0,
      presence_penalty=0)

    if 'choices' in response:
        x = response['choices']
        if len(x) > 0:
            return x[0]['text']
        else:
            return ''
    else:
        return ''



answer = runSomeCode()
print(answer)
```

But I want to figure out given a python code block like the following, can I get the embedding from codex?

Input:

```
import Random
a = random.randint(1,12)
b = random.randint(1,12)
for i in range(10):
    question = "What is "+a+" x "+b+"? "
    answer = input(question)
    if answer = a*b
        print (Well done!)
    else:
        print("No.")
```

Output:

- Embedding of the input code

Comment: You can refer to [this part of OpenAI document](https://beta.openai.com/docs/guides/embeddings/code-search-embeddings).

Comment: @Exploring I am exploring OpenAI, however I don't understand your question clearly to provide an accurate answer. Could you add more details to explain what is the input you will give, what's the process (I can work on this), and what's the output you're seeking?

Comment: @IamAshKS I have to generate embedding for code snippets. These code snippets could be written in Java or JavaScript.

Comment: @Exploring I updated my answer based your clarification. Please check.

Comment: @IamAshKS Whats the dimension for these embeddings?

Comment: @Exploring As you can check in references given in my answer (esp. https://beta.openai.com/docs/guides/embeddings/code-search-embeddings), the dimensions are dependent on the engine or model: Ada (1024 dimensions) and
Babbage (2048 dimensions) for code search engines.

Comment: @IamAshKS is Ada better than Babbage? In other words are larger dimensions better than smaller dimensions?

Comment: @Exploring It is out of scope for this question. Please create another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `get_embedding` will give us an embedding for an input text.

Canonical code from OpenAI here: https://github.com/openai/openai-python/blob/main/examples/embeddings/Get_embeddings.ipynb

```
import openai
from tenacity import retry, wait_random_exponential, stop_after_attempt

@retry(wait=wait_random_exponential(min=1, max=20), stop=stop_after_attempt(6))
def get_embedding(text: str, engine="text-similarity-davinci-001") -> List[float]:

    # replace newlines, which can negatively affect performance.
    text = text.replace("\n", " ")

    return openai.Embedding.create(input=[text], engine=engine)["data"][0]["embedding"]

embedding = get_embedding("Sample query text goes here", engine="text-search-ada-query-001")
print(len(embedding))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, OpenAI can create embedding for any input text -- even if it's code. You only need to pass the correct engine or model in its `get_embedding()` function call. I tested out this code:

```py
# Third-party imports
import openai

from openai.embeddings_utils import get_embedding


openai.api_key = OPENAI_SEC_KEY


embedding = get_embedding("""
    def sample_code():
        print("Hello from IamAshKS !!!")
""", engine="code-search-babbage-code-001")

print()
print(f"{embedding=}")
print(f"{len(embedding)=}")

# OUTPUT:
# embedding=[-0.007094269152730703, 0.006055716425180435, -0.005044757854193449, ...]
# len(embedding)=2048


embedding = get_embedding("""
import Random
a = random.randint(1,12)
b = random.randint(1,12)
for i in range(10):
    question = "What is "+a+" x "+b+"? "
    answer = input(question)
    if answer = a*b
        print (Well done!)
    else:
        print("No.")
""", engine="code-search-babbage-code-001")

print()
print(f"{embedding=}")
print(f"{len(embedding)=}")

# OUTPUT:
# embedding=[-0.011341490782797337, -0.005919027142226696, 0.0011923711281269789, ...]
# len(embedding)=2048
```

**NOTE:** You can replace the model or engine using `engine` parameter for `get_embedding()`.

The above given code gets you embeddings for any code. There is another engine/model for code search named `code-search-ada-code-001` but it's less powerful than `code-search-babbage-code-001`, which I used for this answer. If you also want to do code search, go through references below.

**References:**

- https://openai.com/blog/introducing-text-and-code-embeddings/
- https://beta.openai.com/docs/guides/embeddings/code-search-embeddings
- https://beta.openai.com/docs/guides/embeddings/use-cases#expander-7

Comment: Btu this is text-similarity though and not code embedding. Isnt it?

Comment: does the code needs to be complete? Or incomplete code snippet is ok?

Comment: whats the length of the code that I can feed here?

Comment: @Exploring Code snippets are always complete: they need not be runnable, right? OpenAI works with less or more, complete or incomplete code though it works better for function like code snippets, per my experiments. Also, I am not sure of the code snippet length you can feed, but it should be long enough (I think it will work until you surpass limit of single web request or upload (vs. multipart upload)), i.e., the limit is quite quite long. Hope these answer your questions. Thanks!

Comment: for my case code snippet is not complete. Do you have any experience how embedding works our for incomplete works with the Codex model?

Comment: @Exploring It is out of scope for this question. Please create another question.